# Excel Countif 0, 00, 000 separate entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I want to count `0`, `00` and `000` in my data which is formatted as TEXT but the `countif()` formula gives me same value for each of the three search criteria.

Please find the attached image for more details

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a programming language instead?

Answer (score 4):

The problem occurs because Excel will evaluate each cell in the column A with the expressions "=000", "=00" and "=0", witch are obviously the same (zeros inside the expressions are not quoted, therefore are numbers), although not what we would expect.

You can use my Excel's favorite Swiss knife, the `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A$12=B2))
```

The double minus sign will force the boolean expression into 1 (true) or 0 (false).

Answer (score 1):

Strange, it seems you can't prevent Excel converting text to numbers when possible.

Here is a workaround with an array formula (need to enter using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

`=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$12=B2,1,0))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Forget all the VBA and over complicated sum statements the LEN function in excel counts the character string. If you have leading or trailing spaces use the TRIM function first but it's probably as simple as =LEN(A2).

To work around anything other than a string of zeros I would use =IFERROR(IF(B1*"1"=0,LEN(B1),0),0) the IFERROR handles that "X" and by multiplying the text string of zeros by "1" you convert it to a number so the IF statement will equate it to "0" and run the "value if true" statement LEN(B1)